# Trying to encode a GIF file using giflib

Tags: c++, gif, giflib

I am given image data and color table I am trying to export it as a single frame GIF using giflib. I looked into the API, but can't get it to work. The program crashes even at the first function:

```
GifFileType image_out;
int errorCode = 0;
char* fileName = "SomeName.gif";
image_out = *EGifOpenFileName(fileName,true, &errorCode);
```

It is my understanding that I first need to open a file by specifying it's name and then update it with fileHandle. Then Fill in the screen description, the extension block the image data and add the 3B ending to the file. Then use EGifSpew to export the whole gif. The problem is that I can't even use EGifOpenFileName(); The program crashes at that line.

Can someone help me the API of giflib? This problem is getting really frustrating. 
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

For the purposes of simple encoding I do not want to specify a color table and I just want to encode a single frame GIF.

Comment: The prototype is `GifFileType *EGifOpenFileName(char *GifFileName, bool GifTestExistance, int *ErrorCode)`, how is your code compiled?

Comment: I forgot to add "true" in between. I understand that one would prefer writing GifFileType *image_in = EGifOpenFileName(fileName, true, &ErrorCode), but this way is just as valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype is:

```
GifFileType *EGifOpenFileName(char *GifFileName, bool GifTestExistance, int *ErrorCode)
```

You should write as

```
GifFileType* image_out = EGifOpenFileName(fileName,true, &errorCode);
```

Note `GifFileType` is not POD type so you should **NOT** copy like that.

Comment: Ok, that was the issue. I am curious though why is ```GifFileType* image_out = EGifOpenFileName(fileName,true, &errorCode);``` This work but ```GifFileType* image_out; image_out =EGifOpenFileName(fileName,true, &errorCode);```  fail to compile.